# PowerBi CountDistinct and Average

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following table:

[image: Table Image]

I need the units per hour to countDistinct by the individual date, but average when it is roleld up into the month. My current measure is:

```html
unitsPerHour = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('Workmax Time - Open and Batched'[units]),
    SUM('Workmax Time - Open and Batched'[totalHours])
)
```

How can I update this expression to reflect this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Posting for others for future reference.

```
    crewSizeWAvg = 
CALCULATE (
        AVERAGEX (
            VALUES ( 'Workmax Time - Open and Batched'[inTimeDateRawDateOnly] ),
            CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Workmax Time - Open and Batched'[employee_id] ) )
        ))
```